# After upgrading hightcharts from 4.2.0 to 5.0.7 only a black box is displayed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a site where I have used highcharts for some years with no problem. Original version was 4.2.0.

I tried to update to version 5.0.7 by downloading directly from highcharts site. Then, I replaced the corresponding script tags to reflect the change. However, with that change, I only get a black box where the graph should be.

This is how the highchart is initialized:

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                backgroundColor: null
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Resumen Comparativo Inter-Zonas País (' + meses[periodo % 100 - 1] + '-' + Math.floor(periodo / 100) + ')',
                style: {
                    "fontSize": "14px"
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: zonas
            },
            yAxis: [{
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Totales por Zonas y País'
                }
            }, {
                min: -1000000000,
                title: {
                    text: 'No Encontrados',
                    style: {
                        color: '#B2455E'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: '#B2455E'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true,
                reversed: false
            }],
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
                shared: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Repetidos',
                type: 'column',
                data: getMontosPorCondicion(inventarios, 'REPETIDO', null)
            }, {
                name: 'Resellados',
                type: 'column',
                data: getMontosPorCondicion(inventarios, 'RESELLADO', null)
            }, {
                name: 'Abiertos',
                type: 'column',
                data: getMontosPorCondicion(inventarios, 'ABIERTO', '#8BBC22')
            }, {
                color: '#B2455E',
                name: 'No Encontrados',
                type: 'spline',
                yAxis: 1,
                marker: {
                    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    lineColor: null,
                    lineWidth: 2
                },
                data: getMontosPorCondicion(inventarios, 'NO ENCONTRADO', '#B2455E')
            }]
        });
```

Any help?

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: no errors.... I have already checked

Comment: Have you verified that there weren't any breaking changes from 4.2 to 5.0 that you were using?

Comment: apparently no changes...... and in fact... by inspecting the graph using firebug, I can see the graph is there with all elements. The fact is that appears the whole container with black background. To  test, I have disabled all external CSS files that may be interrfering and JS files belonging to highchart are being loaded last. With all those tests I had not luck.

Comment: Can you repro this in a fiddle by chance?

Comment: Also - try changing the `backgroundColor` to an actual color for a test... `backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'`

Comment: This is very very strange.... I have isolated the chart. The final fact is that when I load the javascript code using <script src="/Scripts/highcharts/5.0.7/highcharts.js"></script> it does not work, however, when I load it from internet using <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> it DOES work. Strange, isn't it? local javascript version is the one I have downloaded from http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts. Is there some explanation about this strange behaviour?

Comment: Possible caching issue? Try moving the file location and make sure you're 100% loading that file - check the network tab to make sure it pulls the right JS file

Comment: No... caching is not the possibility... i have even compared local javascript version with remote one and they are the same. I have thought about a possibility. Maybe this is a compatibility problem with jquery. I am using jquery 1.12.4 and when I use remote version, it is likely it is downloading a standalone version of highchart... I am almost sure this is the problem because when using fiddler, I did not load jquery files and it works.

Comment: It is possible that you downloaded a styled version of Highcharts which required additional css file.You can read more about it [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) - without css, it renders like this http://jsfiddle.net/qt25xpz5/

Comment: thanks @morganfree. I had the same issuue.
I have ES6/webpack2 project.
imported `import Highcharts from 'highcharts/js/highcharts.js'`
And saw black box too.
Then I added `import 'highcharts/css/highcharts.css';` and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your copy of highcharts.js might be different from the cdn https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js. Replace the codes in your copy with that of the cdn. This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You additionally need to add [highcharts.css](https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css) to your page.

As per the [highcharts site](https://code.highcharts.com/):
"If you are styling your charts using CSS, load the javascript files from the /js/ directory. For these files, presentational code is removed, and CSS is required to style the chart."